# Two things to do in MySQL IF()

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean-logic

I have a problem concerning the IF() function in MySQL.

I would like to return a string and change the value of a variable. Somwhat like:

`IF(@firstRow=1, "Dear" AND @firstRow:=0, "dear")`

This outputs only '0' instead of 'Dear'...

I would be  very thankful for some input on ways I could solve this problem!

Louis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` is a boolean operator, not a "also do this other thing" operator.

`"Dear" AND 0` returns 0 because 0 is treated as `false` in MySQL and `<anything> AND false` will return `false`.

Also because the integer/boolean value of `"Dear"` is 0 as well. Using a string in a numeric context just reads initial digits in the string, if any, and ignores the rest.

It's not clear what your problem is, but I guess you want to capitalize the word "dear" if the row is the first one in the result set.

Instead of being too clever by half trying to fit the side-effect into your expression, do yourself a favor and break it out into a separate column:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(@firstRow=1, 'Dear', 'dear'), @firstRow:=0 AS _ignoreThis
    -> FROM (SELECT @firstRow:=1) AS _init
    -> CROSS JOIN
    -> mytable;
+---------------------------------+-------------+
| IF(@firstRow=1, 'Dear', 'dear') | _ignoreThis |
+---------------------------------+-------------+
| Dear                            |           0 |
| dear                            |           0 |
| dear                            |           0 |
+---------------------------------+-------------+
```

But if you really want to make your code as confusing and unreadable as possible, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT IF(@firstRow=1, CONCAT('Dear', IF(@firstRow:=0, '', '')), 'dear')
FROM (SELECT @firstRow:=1) AS _init
CROSS JOIN
...
```

But remember this important metric of code quality: **WTFs per minute**.

[image]

Comment: I know that it's not that clean but the first version doesn't work for some reason, I had tried that already... The second version works fine though^^ Thanks! :)

Comment: @siuol, I tested the first query and it works fine. See above, I pasted what I tested.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case expression` instead of IF() as the syntax is far easier to follow e.g.

```
select
      case when @firstRow = 1 then 'Dear' else 'dear' end AS Salutation
    , @firstRow := 0
from (         
    select 1  n union all
    select 2  n union all
    select 3
    ) d
cross join (SELECT @firstRow:=1) var


+---+------------+----------------+
|   | Salutation | @firstRow := 0 |
+---+------------+----------------+
| 1 | Dear       |              0 |
| 2 | dear       |              0 |
| 3 | dear       |              0 |
+---+------------+----------------+
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/FRPJ52855)